# confusion with the jumplist of vim

Tags: vim, jump-list

everyone, i have some confusion with the moving of  and  in jumplist of vim.
i think it's not so suitable for code understanding. suppose that we have some code like:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("vim-go")
    hello_world()
    final_answer()
}

func hello_world() {
    hello()
    world()
}

func hello() {
    hello1()
}

func hello1() {}

func world() {
    world1()
}

func world1() {}

func final_answer() {
    final()
    answer()
}

func final() {
    final1()
}

func final1() {
}

func answer() {
    answer1()
}

func answer1() {}
```

and now i would like to understand what the main function do. So, i have to
figoure what the hello_world and final_answer function do and hello, world, final ...
the path to understand all of this function i think should be
[the understand path i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWUhD.png)

while when use  and  to browse the code , i got some jump path like this:

[the actual jump list of vim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujHIp.png)

the jumplist of vim is not consistent with the code path i want at step 9 in the pictures.

The way i want is that when i press  from the call of world() in function hello_world, i can jump back to the call of hello_world() in main but not the definition of hello1().

anyone know if i use the jumplist of vim the wrong way?
or how can i jump back to hello_world when i press  at world()?

Comment: well the vim jump list has nothing to do with code at all. It remembers your last jumps in the textfile (cursor positions).

Answer (score 1):

finally, i found a macro in https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/mark.c#L155

as the comment say

> If last used entry is not at the top, put it at the top by rotating
> the stack until it is (the newer entries will be at the bottom).
> Keep one entry (the last used one) at the top.

By adding one line in src/Makefile:

> EXTRA_DEFS += -DJUMPLIST_ROTATE

and recompile the vim, i can get what i want.

Comment: Wow, that's quite surprising! Today I learned. Thanks for digging down and figuring out the source of this behavior.

Comment: while , the JUMPLIST_ROTATE has been removed since [this commit](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/ab55f11d9bc776d546794748bc62ac47d5340c2e)